# Mac OS X Lion Screensaver on Locked Screen

Tags: mac, osx-lion, operating-systems, screensaver, login-screen

I have a screensaver set in my system preferences, but when I lock my screen either with Alfred or clicking on the user profile menu and hitting "Login Window...", it runs a different screensaver.

**Is there a way to change the screensaver on that login page?** Perhaps it's like setting the screen save for the sudo user (sorta).

Cheers!

Josh

Comment: You could remove the X tag. OS X doesn't use the X window system.

Comment: @ggustafsson What's that now?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16514/how-can-i-set-the-mac-os-x-screensaver-when-not-logged-in):

> The screensaver for the login screen is the one set for the root (i.e. system) user account

I tried running the terminal command the user suggests, but it was a bit grumpy about a missing folder. After creating the folder with:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/root/Library/PreferencePanes
```

...executing the `System Preferences` again ran without the previous error and opened preferences as root.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure OS X is not set to display a random screensaver? It's on by default.

[image: System Preferences]

Comment: Nope, it works fine when I'm logged in.

Comment: Then i don't have a clue.